# How to pronounce adverb "often"?

Tags: pronunciation

Some people pronounce it with a [t] sound, so it is like [ˈɒf.tən]. Others omit the [t]. Which is more correct, or does it depend on the dialect or the speaker etc? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to be rude but Google search can give you tons of millions of valid sources telling you how to pronounce "**often**".

For instance:

> The medial \t\ dropped out of many common words formed with -en, but came back in often. It is common today, but still stigmatized with the label ÷ in the dictionary; some educated speakers certainly do use it, but others consider it unacceptable. And they will often correct you. *([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/correct-pronunciation-of-often))*
>
> The pronunciation (ȯf-tən), which is not recognized in dictionaries, is now frequent in the south of England, and is often used in singing. *(Oxford English Dictionary added this note to its entry for often)*
>
> The pronunciation ȯf-tən, until recently generally considered as more or less illiterate, is not uncommon among the educated in some sections, and is often used in singing. *(1934 unabridged Webster’s Second)*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/often), which I favour a lot, gives both *(however the former is most common)*:

- **UK** - /ˈɒf.ən/ /ˈɒf.tən/
- **US** - /ˈɑːf.ən/ /ˈɑːf.tən/

> A quote from **H. W. Fowler** in *Modern English Usage*:
>
> [the pronunciation of the t in often] is practised by two oddly consorted classes—the academic speakers who affect a more precise enunciation than their neighbours…& the uneasy half-literates who like to prove that they can spell….”
>
> *OED2*, **R. W. Burchfield**:
>
> Nowadays…many standard speakers use both  [AWF-in] and [AWF-tin], but the former pronunciation is the more common of the two.

[Reference to Daily writing Tips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/how-do-you-pronounce-often/).

Comment: Thanks, SovereignSun. I'm sorry if this is a simple question. It's not extra easy for me. I want to progress in reputation on StackExchange but I still cannot understand very well which questions are well accepted. Simple questions which can be googled are not welcome but complex ones like proofreading aren't either.

Comment: @Alexander I can't be telling you this, probably, but this site isn't about reputation. Your question may be voted to be closed based on the "**[Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary)**"